# Do aeroshells really get hotter than the surface of the sun?

Tags: reentry, curiosity, thermal, heat-shield, mars-science-laboratory

[image: Google, how hot is the surface of the Sun?]

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48286) to *How to design heatshield bluntness?* says:

> Curiosity reentry dumped about 98% of its entry energy into the atmosphere, **the aeroshell can still get to be temps greater than the surface of the sun.**

Of course the surface of the Sun is a bit ambiguous and the temperature of the photosphere varies by 1000 K every 70 kilometers, the technical definition of the surface is usually the point at which the visible light opacity reaches 2/3, (see [What is the density profile within the Sun's photosphere? Which one of these is wrong?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32727)) but since we're talking about "white hot" things we can use something like the best fit to the Sun's spectrum or it's effective color temperature of [almost 5,800 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power).

That's pretty close to the temperature near the Sun's photosphere as it should be.

**Question:** Are there really parts of the aeroshell that get this hot? Or is that the temperature of the gas or plasma nearby?

For example, ASTM's 2015 news item [New material has higher melting point than any known substance](https://www.asminternational.org/web/cmdnetwork/home/-/journal_content/56/10180/25655039/NEWS) says:

> Computations show that a material made with just the right amounts of hafnium, nitrogen, and carbon **would have a melting point of more than 4400 K (7460°F). That's about two-thirds the temperature at the surface of the sun and 200 K higher than the highest melting point ever recorded experimentally.**

See also https://matmatch.com/learn/material/metals-high-melting-point

Comment: related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15038/6944

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://spaceflight101.com/msl/msl-aeroshell-and-heat-shield/) says 1,930°C (2,200K) for Curiosity, which seem in line with peak Orion and Apollo values from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15042/8693), 2,200°C (2,470K) and 5,000°F (3,000K).

As such, the surface material does not reach solar temperatures.

However, [the gas and plasma immediately next to it](https://ngpdlab.engin.umich.edu/ablation/surface-chemical-processes) can easily reach 10x solar temperature, and what is "surface" of the Sun other gas and plasma :)

> Question: Are there really parts of the aeroshell that get this hot? Or is that the temperature of the gas or plasma nearby?

The later then, it is.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! When it comes to *material temperature*, errors of a factor of 2 or 3 are pretty egregious :-)